# Dispatching in an HTML/Javascript Application

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am in the process of creating an HTML application, in the sense that there will only be one HTML page and the rest will be done as AJAX using jQuery.

I will be storing context in the hash of the URL to preserve the back button and allow external deep-linking from our main site.  I will use `onhashchange` to detect a request for new content.  With that, I would use a link such as `<a href="#product/sku-1">Link</a>` to cause the application to go GET /api/product/sku-1.js as JSON, after which I would need a dispatch strategy to route that JSON to the proper renderer.

My initial thought was a set of regexes in `onhashchange` to set the callback of the ajax call based on the requested resource, but that makes a large assumption that rendering is always the same for any given resource.  I don't have any current requirements that this assumption breaks, but I hate to tie my hands this early in the game.

Have any of you any advice to offer on patterns that work for this problem?  I can think of at least 3 ways to handle this right now, but I'd like some insight from anyone who has had a prior experience with this before I make a command decision and move out.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify - are you planning to use a js page as the AJAX server? Why not use a webservice model? That way you can just have one webservice URL and call whatever functions as necessary with parameters derived from the # bookmark.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem of dispatching to the proper renderer.  Basically I needed a mapping that said, "when this hash pattern is clicked, go get this remote resource and then route the response to this renderer."

Comment: Ah render as in transform into html? I've never tried that before, instead i've always deserialised it and put the resulting values into the DOM one way or another. I have to maintain XSLT transforms of XML at work and I don't love that approach, but perhaps that's substantially different.

Comment: btw i'm probably in over my head here but i was intrigued by the question.

Comment: Correct, if I am going to go download a list of products, it has to be rendered into markup somewhere.  The plan is to write the application entirely in html5 and js.